# Angular ui-select field entry uuid cannot be created

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

i have a ui-select field in my angular codebase where the entries are present as an array object. But when i try to add/remove anything, i get the following error:

> Cannot create property 'id' on string 'xxx'

where xxx is a newly added field.

In select.js, error comes at this line:

```
$select.selected[j].id = $select.selected[j].uuid;
```

this uuid comes as undefined.

below is the template fragment:

```html
<ui-select multiple
    tagging
    data-ng-disabled="!field.editable"
    data-ng-model="model[qualifier]"
    theme="select2"
    title=""
    sortable="true"
    style="width: 100%;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{field.tooltip| translate}}"
        name="{{field.qualifier}}">
        <span id="myfield-{{field.qualifier}}">{{$item}}</span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices id="{{field.qualifier}}-myfield"
        repeat="option in model[qualifier]| filter: $select.search">
        <small>
            <span>{{option}}</span>
        </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is looking fine but when you get `undefined` error, it means you are reading `uuid` which does not exist, or exists but is not defined - does not have a value.

Solution is to check if you are setting the value correctly to all indexes containing `uuid` which you are later reading.

Comment: currently none of the indexes are setting the uuid value, since on removal of field i get the same error. Where exactly can i check for the same?